# A webapplication with millions of database roles

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm working on JSF project where I in one webapplication have many users each with an account and a separate password, and back-end the application is connected to a PostgreSQL database. I want the most tight security possible and therefore would like to create a system where, if the JSF webapplication get hacked/compromised, then there will not be access to most of the user accounts in the database (I expect the database to run on a separate server (or separate servers if necessary) hosted by a secured OpenBSD OS).

I think that normally a webapplication connect to a database as a role with a password and then the application has direct access to all the users in the database (for that webapplication). But to make it more secure I am thinking about giving each client user of the webapplication a separate role in the database (each with a separate password of-course). But then there will become millions of roles in the database, and therefore I would like to ask if anyone else have experience with this, and the performance penalties that might occur from using such a design?

And what will happen if the system gets very popular (such as Facebook) and maybe the needs for roles grows to several hundreds of millions (just setting up a best-case scenario)? Will such a design become a dead end?

Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't sound sensible.  What would be the purpose of these millions of roles?  (i.e. how would their privileges differ?)

Comment: The purpose is that each role only have access privileges to one row (and each client user fits into only one row seen vertically). Then if the server gets hacked and monitored by a hacker, then only accounts that are being accessed by users while the hacker is into the system will be compromised (I can just reinstall the server running the Tomcat server regularly to clean out rootkits etc. that a hacker might have created there).

Comment: Are per-row privileges available?

Comment: the first line of that page implies that it's not available ;)

Comment: Yes: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Row-security

Comment: I am sorry that I got the comments mixes up a bit as I wanted to fix a grammar mistake and therefore deleted my comment to recreate it. Therefore the order is a bit screwed up!

Comment: Anyway, then I think that I have read somewhere that it is possible on PostgreSQL already, but maybe it is just in development phase. But it should be possible om Oracle DB already and also it is possible with MySQL: http://www.sqlmaestro.com/resources/all/row_level_security_mysql/

Comment: I really doubt that individual user roles will be appropriate. In PostgreSQL at least, I won't be too surprised if tens/hundreds of thousands of roles has scaling issues; I'm not aware of anyone who's tested it anyway. I'd try to concentrate users into roles, and just `SET ROLE` for a group of users.

Comment: @KimJensen Row Security is in-progress, it's not committed to PostgreSQL 9.4. It might be available in 9.5.

Comment: I have had experience with postgres systems with thousands of roles with no problems.  I used roles in way you describe.  I created a separate schema, and my roles only have permission in that schema.  Also, I didn't let the roles touch the base tables, all of their access was through views in the schema they have access to. Using a view I created rules that limited access to that appropriate for that user (role).  Even if the user has direct access to the db, they can only access data available to their role. This app peaked at about 10K roles with no issues.

Comment: @Craig Ringer: I am very happy to hear that is in progress and hopefully will be available in PsotgreSQL 9.5, as I like PostgreSQL very much because it reliable and stable, and probably faster than MySQL when dealing with advanced queries! Hopefully it will also get faster when doing simple queries! But the question still is if it can handle millions of roles with good performance?

Comment: @Greg: That's very interesting. Because if PostgreSQL can handle the setup you describe without having performance problems, then when row-based privileges comes (which I suppose will be a more lightweight technology) it might be possible to handle millions of users with row-level privileges without getting performance problems!

Comment: I just went and read the row level security wiki for postgres.  I know there are corner cases, but, you can get the same level of security with views.  You will need another table with the user's relationship to the row, then your view/rules restrict insert/update/delete/select appropriately.  I agree with Craig Ringer about the unknown ability for postgres to handle that many roles.  It would be easy enough to find out, right?  Create a database with a million roles and see what happens :-)

Comment: @Greg: Thanks for the input. I think that your solution is very smart, but also I think that it might be a relatively heavy burden for the database to handle. So I'm hoping that when direct row-level security hopefully comes in PostgreSQL that it will be lightweight! About just creating 1 million roles, then you are right but in a real world implementation it might behave differently! But then of-course I could create a complex test system! But maybe someone has already tried this in real life with millions of users? Anyway, it's good to know that you have done it with 10K of users.

Comment: I'm thinking that another solution could be to have a very simple and very secure network computer between the server running Tomcat and the database server. For example it would be possible to program a MCU (with two high-speed ethernet ports) just to validate and store the passwords and so that it's just passing packets through in both directions if user is validated (as a password filtered repeater). I think that a MCU with no OS can be programmed in Assembler to become completely secure (maybe with help from some FPGA's to handle the forwarding of packets)!